# jQuery .load() only being called once

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have had a good search around, and found several answers to this question, trying most, but can't figure why none of the solutions are working.

On any submit in the form, the load() call works, but any subsequent submissions use standard http requests not the ajax call.

Can anyone take a look at my code and tell me what the reason is for this?

```
$('#cart-container form').on('submit',function() {
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        success: cart
    }); 
    return false; 
});

function cart() {
    var path = '/enter/embed-cart';
    $('#cart-container').fadeTo('fast', 0.5).load(path, function() {
        $('#cart-container').fadeTo('fast', 1);
    }); 
}
```

P.S I am using mals up ajax form.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because You are replacing your form in `load`

you can use event delegation to make it work

```
$('#cart-container').on('submit','form',function() {
```

- http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: To clarify: initially an event handler is attached to the form, but after the first `.load` that form is replaced with a new form (they may even look exactly the same but they are different forms). The new form does not have a `submit` handler. It follows that another way to solve the problem is to simply re-attach the handler (to the new form) just after fading in.